# Facebook API: reproductions for a given video post

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Im trying to get reproductions and shares from a certain post (for instance https://www.facebook.com/elvisa.yomastercard.9/posts/1181856505206084)

by using the same request that i use for non-video posts:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/1181856505206084?fields=shares,reactions.summary(true).limit(0),comments.summary(true).limit(0)
```

but seems that shares field is not available for video content as the api returns

> "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (shares) on node
>   type (Video)"

I also tried using %PAGEID%_%POSTID% in the request and It works:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/152666661458412_1181856505206084?fields=shares,reactions.summary(true).limit(0),comments.summary(true).limit(0)
```

but im stuck on finding the way to get video reproductions from a post. Tried getting /insights/page_video_views with no success.

Can somebody give me some light on this?

Comment: What do you mean by “reproductions”?

Comment: I mean "Video views". Thanks

Comment: Getting insights of course requires permission; so you can only get them if you are an admin of the page the video is posted on.

Comment: Thank you CBroe. I though it was public data as it appears on every video post

Comment: Public via the Facebook UI does not mean freely available via the API in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per @Cbroe answer, this cant be get from FB API

Thanks